# File based strings/variables to set file path etc in python operation

Tags: python, file, variables, operation

I am trying to create part of a program that will take the values found in two CFG files and use them to determine what filetype to search for as well as what folder location to use. The code I found online sort of suits my needs, However I would like to not use a hard coded file path. Here is the code I have modified so far:

```
import glob


location = open("config.cfg", encoding = 'cp1252')
location = location.read()


filetype = open("filetype.cfg", encoding = 'cp1252')
filetype = filetype.read()
    

fileset = [file for file in glob.glob(location + filetype, recursive=True)]

print(location)
print(filetype)
for file in fileset:
    print(file)
```

The config.cfg contains one line, which is the file path to a folder with 3 sample JPG files in it.

```
C:/test
```

The `filetype.cfg` contains one line as well, which is the file type to search for

```
"**/*.jpg"
```

I've gotten to the point where this code throws no errors, but it also doesn't work as intended either, it seems to read the files properly, but doesn't list the files in the folder. The `Config.CFG` file contains the folder path, i.e. `C:/test`, while the `filetype.cfg` contains `"**/*.jpg"`, which is the type of file I would like searched for. I found the original code here: https://www.techbeamers.com/python-list-all-files-directory/, Look under the 'glob' method.

The original (fully working) code from the link above:

```
import glob

location = 'c:/test/temp/'

fileset = [file for file in glob.glob(location + "**/*.py", recursive=True)]

for file in fileset:
    print(file)
```

Using Python 3.8 64bit on Windows 10.

Comment: What kind of string does `location + filetype` contain? Your example should be a [mre]. `glob.glob()` takes in a path, so the issue is probably what you're sending to that function as the path.

Comment: What is your question? Your [mre] should always include a minimal example of any data that the program is operating on - especially if the data is in a resource that we cannot access. We should be able to copy and paste from your example and run/tes it.

Comment: Try adding the separator / in the content of config.cfg.

Comment: If filetype.cfg actually contains the double quotes that you show, then you're trying to find files with an extension of `.jpg"`.

Comment: Thanks Jason Harper. That's what was wrong. Removed the quotes in the filetype.cfg and everything works as intended now.

Answer (score 0):

*Moved from an edit to the question by the OP to an answer.*

Remove the quotes around `"**/*.jpg"` in the `filetype.cfg` file:

```
**/*.jpg
```